# How can I get the product of two values to be lower the greater one of the values is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This should be quite a simple question for a lot of people on here.

I have a constant, K, that is being multiplied by a some value M. That is it. Here is the equation:

P=KM

I want P to be lower, the greater the value of M is, and higher the lower the value of M is. It is quite a simple question, but I am having some trouble figuring it out. What should the value of K be to achieve this, or do I need some other variable?

Comment: If everything is positive, you can have it with *inverse proportionality*: $\; P=\dfrac KM$.

Comment: How about setting $K$ to be a negative constant?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add that P must also be positive, and M is always positive in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements (including the requirements you have put in comments but not in your Question) are incompatible.

Your formula $P = KM$ is a linear formula with independent variable $M$, dependent variable $P$ and parameter $K$.  You require $P$ and $M$ are simultaneously positive, so $K$ is positive.  The graph of $P$ versus $K$ is a line that passes through the origin.  Since you require $P$ and $M$ both positive, this line passes through the first quadrant, so its slope, $K$ is positive.

Since the graph is necessarily lower on the left and higher on the right, i.e., $P$ is lower when $M$ is lower and $P$ is greater when $M$ is greater, your collection of requirements is impossible to satisfy.

One term for this situation is "[directly proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Direct_proportionality)".  The equation $P = KM$ says that $P$ varies directly with $M$.  If $K$ can be negative, then then larger $P$s correspond with smaller $M$s and vice versa, *but* $P$ and $M$ have opposite signs.  Since you require $P$ and $M$ to have the same sign, no direct variation can produce the relationship between larger and smaller values of $P$ and $M$ you request.

Alternatively, one can allow $P$ and $M$ are [inversely proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Inverse_proportionality), $P = K/M$.  Then any positive $K$ producse the relationship between larger and smaller values of $P$ and $M$ you request and also $P$ and $M$ are simultaneously positive.